# How to apply transform rotations to reflect an object's trajectory in 2D Pong?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a simple 2D Pong game, but I'm unable to get the ball `GameObject` to move based on its rotation when applying the following logic:

`transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * ballSpeed;`

The above code only changes the ball movement along the z-axis.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BallMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float ballSpeed = 20f;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 _rotation;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * ballSpeed;
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        _rotation = new Vector3(transform.rotation.x * -1, transform.rotation.y * -1, 0);
        transform.Rotate(_rotation * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rytro. Assuming that you're attempting to reflect the ball when it collides with a paddle, you could use the built-in [Vector3.Reflect](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Reflect.html) method to calculate the reflected direction of the ball.

Comment: @Juris or maybe [`Vector2.Reflect`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Reflect.html) as this is about 2D anyway

Comment: Agreed, `Vector2` is better, given @Rytro is only working in 2D space!

Answer (score 1):

1. While working with 2 dimensions, try using Vector2, instead of Vector3, as it uses only x and y axes. Then you don't have to deal with the third dimension and it makes things a little bit easier.
2. transform.forward makes your object move forward from the original position on the z axes. That's the blue arrow on your object while using move tool in 3D. Use transform.up, or -transform.up to move up and down, or transform.right, or -transform.right to move rigtht and left.

Comment: Adding to this: the usage of `transform.rotation` of OP is bluntly wrong.. It is a quaternion and its `x` and `y` components have fairly little to do with X and Y axis of the world ;) a quaternion is not in euler space